# 404 Not Found in Yii2 regarding API new module

Tags: api, url, yii2

I am developing `Yii2 project` where create api module in it but have a issue to call api where g`ot error of page not found.`

How to call that api controller which i created. I Run below url for api call.

The requested `URL /project/project_name/api/v1/api/login` was not found on this server.

What i have to change or any `configuration required` for it. I am missing something anywhere. Any one have experience or trick to solved it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you included the api module in main.php file? Check on this link http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

Comment: /project/project_name/api/v1/api/login is not an URL, it is a path to a file from what I figure. If you want to make a call to an API you need to use a  proper URL.

Comment: I did it. Actually i forgot to add /web in url. Thanks for comments

Answer (score 1):

Adding below code into my main.php solved the 404 not found issue:

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'user',
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

I was trying to set enableStrictParsing to true for the urlManager but still the same then try this,

'enableStrictParsing' => false,

[Ref. Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61616-restful-web-services-not-found-404/)

Answer (score 0):

It can cause by two reasons:

1. Module is not loaded. You must add it to your `config/web.php` (Or if this module may run under Command environment, also add to `config/console.php`) under `modules` key.
2. Your routing is not well-configured. For fix, you can add your url as key and value to your `UrlManager` module on `config/web.php` and try for browsing. If it fixed that, you can define a pattern for your url.

If any help is needed, please do not hesitate to submit comment on my answer.